# JavaScript "firstNonRepeatingLetter" function returning undefined instead of a character?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, undefined

Here is the problem statement:

**Write a function named firstNonRepeatingLetter† that takes a string input, and returns the first character that is not repeated anywhere in the string.**

**For example, if given the input 'stress', the function should return 't', since the letter t only occurs once in the string, and occurs first in the string.**

**As an added challenge, upper- and lowercase letters are considered the same character, but the function should return the correct case for the initial letter. For example, the input 'sTreSS' should return 'T'.**

Below is my code, which returns undefined. I'm not able to catch the error.

```js
function firstNonRepeatingLetter(s) {
  var x = s.replace(" ", "");
  for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    if (x.charCodeAt(i) < 96) {
     
      var y = x.replace(x[i], "");
      var z = String.fromCharCode(x.charCodeAt(i) + 32);
      if (y.indexOf(x[0]) > -1 || y.indexOf(z) > -1) {
        continue;
      } else {
        var m = x[i];
      }
      return m;
    } else if (x.charCodeAt(i) > 96) {
      
      var y = x.replace(x[i], "");
      var z = String.fromCharCode(x.charCodeAt(i) - 32);
      if (y.indexOf(x[0]) > -1 || y.indexOf(z) > -1) {
        continue;
      } else {
        var m = x[i];
      }
      return m;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You have an **if** and and **else if**... but no ***else***... as such if you don't meet the first 2 if conditions you will return undefined.

Comment: Please try using the [debugging capabilities](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Debugging/Debugging_JavaScript) of your browser. You’ve used `console.log` to log the result. Why not log the relevant variables within your function, or use `debugger`?

Comment: @Xufox ah yes, I jumped in too soon... looking again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your conditions `y.indexOf(x[0]) > -1` are incorrect. You don’t need to compare the *first* character, but the `i`th character. Replace both of them by `y.indexOf(x[i]) > -1`.

---

Some hints:

- ***Please** avoid single-letter variable names*. They make it incredibly hard to debug and understand your code.
- `var` declarations inside blocks, like `for`, `if`, etc. don’t do anything useful. You’ve redeclared `var m` twice. This just adds to the confusion.
- `.replace(" ", "")` only removes the first space, even though you probably meant to remove *all spaces*. Either use regexes (also useful to add more cases, or to limit your inputs to specific characters), or use [`replaceAll`](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-string-replace-all) (note the browser compatibility and proposal state). Using regexes might look like `.replace(/\s/g, "")` to remove *all whitespace*, or `.replace(/[^a-z]/gi, "")` to remove anything that isn’t a Latin letter.
- Instead of adding or subtracting `32` from a charcode, just use [`.toUpperCase`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toUpperCase) and [`.toLowerCase`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase).
- Likewise, comparing charcodes *smaller or greater than* `96` won’t handle the character with this exact charcode, which is the `` ` `` character. Instead, consider converting the entire string to either uppercase or lowercase, rather than handling both in two separate cases.
- Lastly, depending on whether the assignment allows for that, consider using [`Object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object#Methods_of_the_Object_constructor) and [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Methods) methods.

---

These are two ways how the function can be written in ECMAScript 2015+:

```
const getFirstUniqueLetter = (string) => {
  string = [...string.replace(/\s/g, "")];

  const {
    map,
    unique
  } = string.reduce((result, character) => {
      result.map[character.toLowerCase()] = (result.map[character.toLowerCase()] || 0) + 1;

      if(!result.unique.includes(character)){
        result.unique.push(character);
      }

      return result;
    }, {
      map: {},
      unique: []
    });

  // You can add the `|| ""` in the next line to get a default output of the empty string, if no character is unique. Otherwise, `undefined` is returned.
  return unique.find((character) => map[character.toLowerCase()] === 1) /* || "" */;
};
```

```js
const getFirstUniqueLetter = (string) => {
  string = string.replace(/\s/g, "");

  // You can add the `|| ""` in the next line to get a default output of the empty string, if no character is unique. Otherwise, `undefined` is returned.
  return [...string].find((character) => string.match(new RegExp(character, "gi")).length === 1) /* || "" */;
};
```

Comment: I thought by using replace I was "deleting" the first character of the given string. That's why I was taking '0' index in every iteration.

Comment: @Xufox You've complemented your answer with the hint on `replace` only substituting the first occurrence of the pattern. In fact, the exercise does not seem to cater for the case that all characters repeat.

Comment: @collapsar To be honest, I don’t know what you mean. It seems that `.replace(" ", "")` is supposed to remove all whitespace, but it doesn’t do that.

Comment: @Xufox The wording on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) isn't particularly clear since they mainly consider the case of the first argument being a RegExp, but calling `.replace` calls for the replacement of the first pattern/string occurrence only.

Comment: @Xufox: In the latest [ECMA specs](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-string.prototype.replace), however, the behavior is well-defined (though hard to grok)

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't solve your code as written, but I thought I'd provide an alternative approach.

```js
    function firstNonRepeatingLetter(s){
      var allCharacters = s.split('');
      var character;
      var characterMap = {};
      //get all character counts
      for(var i=0;i<allCharacters.length;i++){
        character = allCharacters[i];
        if(typeof(characterMap[character]) == 'undefined'){
          characterMap[character] = 0;
        }
        characterMap[character]++;
      }
      //remove any duplicates
      for(var c in characterMap){
        if(characterMap[c] > 1){
          delete characterMap[c];
        }
      }
      //find the first character in your string that is *still* in the map
      for(var i=0;i<allCharacters.length;i++){
        character = allCharacters[i];
        if(typeof(characterMap[character]) != 'undefined'){
          return character;
        }
      }
      //all characters in the string were duplicated (e.g. "ABBA")
      return 'No non repeating letters';
    }
    
    console.log(firstNonRepeatingLetter("stress"));
    console.log(firstNonRepeatingLetter("doodle"));
    console.log(firstNonRepeatingLetter("abba"));
    console.log(firstNonRepeatingLetter("supercalifragilisticexpialidocious"));
```